# Clips rules - conditional firings of rules

Tags: rules, rule-engine, clips

I am trying to use rules for an agriculture based system

So for example,

based on location --> list crops --> based on crop selected --> select seed

This is a forward chaining problem

I am only able to define the rules statically. Meaning, defining rules for every possible scenario

Is there a way to code, say if I select a location, I get a list of all crops, and when the user selects the crop , I get the list of seeds

How do I make sure, the rules are fired based on the output of the previous rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can take is to represent the questions as facts and then write general rules for processing those facts. First define some deftemplates to represent the questions, the branching from one question to another based on the user's response, and the user's response.

```
(deftemplate question
   (slot name)
   (slot text)
   (slot display-answers (allowed-values yes no))
   (slot last-question (default none)))

(deftemplate branch
   (slot question)
   (slot answer)
   (slot next-question)
   (multislot next-answers))

(deftemplate response
   (slot question)
   (slot answer))
```

Next, define your questions and the branches between them:

```
(deffacts questions
   (question (name location)
             (text "Country")
             (display-answers no)
             (last-question none))
   (question (name crop-type)
             (text "Crop Type")
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question location))
   (question (name seed)
             (text "Seed")
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question crop-type)))

(deffacts locations
   (branch (question location)
           (answer "United States")
           (next-question crop-type)
           (next-answers food fiber))
   (branch (question location)
           (answer "India")
           (next-question crop-type)
           (next-answers food fiber))
   (branch (question location)
           (answer "China")
           (next-question crop-type)
           (next-answers food fiber))
   (branch (question location)
           (answer "Brazil")
           (next-question crop-type)
           (next-answers food fiber))
   (branch (question location)
           (answer "Pakistan")
           (next-question crop-type)
           (next-answers fiber)))

(deffacts crop-types
   (branch (question crop-type)
           (answer fiber)
           (next-question seed)
           (next-answers cotton hemp flax))
   (branch (question crop-type)
           (answer food)
           (next-question seed)
           (next-answers corn wheat rice)))
```

Define some utility deffunctions for processing user responses. These will allow the program to ignore differences in alphabetic case in the user response.

```
(deffunction lenient-eq (?v1 ?v2)
   (if (eq ?v1 ?v2)
      then
      (return TRUE))
   (if (eq (lowcase (str-cat ?v1)) (lowcase (str-cat ?v2)))
      then
      (return TRUE))
   (return FALSE))   
      
(deffunction lenient-member$ (?value $?allowed-values)
   (loop-for-count (?i (length$ ?allowed-values))
      (bind ?v (nth$ ?i ?allowed-values))
      (if (lenient-eq ?value ?v)
         then
         (return ?i)))
   (return FALSE)) 
 
(deffunction ask-question (?question $?allowed-values)
   (printout t ?question)
   (bind ?answer (lowcase (readline)))
   (while (not (lenient-member$ ?answer ?allowed-values)) do
      (printout t ?question)
      (bind ?answer (lowcase (readline))))
   ?answer)
```

Add some rules to handle the case where the list of valid answers are not displayed when the question is asked (because there may be a large number of them).

```
;;; Ask question without valid answers displayed or checked

(defrule ask-question-without-answers

   ;; There is a question that should be 
   ;; displayed without valid answers.

   (question (name ?question)
             (text ?text)
             (display-answers no)
             (last-question ?last-question))

   ;; There is no prior question or
   ;; the prior question has a response.

   (or (test (eq ?last-question none))
       (response (question ?last-question)))

   ;; There is no response to the question.
   
   (not (response (question ?question)))

   =>
   
   ;; Ask the question
   
   (printout t ?text ": ")
   
   ;; Assert a response with the question and answer. 
   
   (assert (response (question ?question)
                     (answer (lowcase (readline))))))

;;; Check for valid response to a question

(defrule bad-answer-to-question

   ;; There is a question that should be 
   ;; displayed without valid answers.

   (question (name ?question)
             (display-answers no))
             
   ;; There is a response to the question.
        
   ?r <- (response (question ?question)
                   (answer ?answer))
   
   ;; The response to the question does
   ;; not branch to another question.
                   
   (not (branch (question ?question) 
                (answer ?a&:(lenient-eq ?a ?answer))))
   =>
   
   ;; Print the list of valid answers for the question.
   
   (printout t "Valid answers are:" crlf)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?b branch))
                     (eq ?b:question ?question)
      (printout t "   " ?b:answer crlf))
      
   ;; Retract the response so that the
   ;; question will be asked again.
   
   (retract ?r))
```

Finally, add a rule to handle the case where the question is asked with the list of valid answers displayed and is immediately check by the ask-question deffunction.

```
;;; Ask questions with valid answers displayed and checked

(defrule ask-question-with-answers

   ;; There is a question that should be 
   ;; displayed including valid answers.
   
   (question (name ?question)
             (text ?text)
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question ?last-question))
   
   ;; The preceding question has been answered.
   
   (response (question ?last-question)
             (answer ?last-answer))
             
   ;; There is a branch from the preceding question
   ;; and its answer to this question and the allowed
   ;; values for the answer.
              
   (branch (answer ?a&:(lenient-eq ?a ?last-answer)) 
           (next-question ?question)
           (next-answers $?next-answers))
   =>  
   
   ;; Construct the question text including the possible answers.
    
   (bind ?text (str-cat ?text " [" (implode$ ?next-answers) "]: "))

   ;; Ask the question.
   
   (bind ?answer (ask-question ?text ?next-answers))

   ;; Assert a response fact with the question and answer.
   
   (assert (response (question ?question) (answer ?answer))))
```

The output when this program is run:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (load "seeds.clp")
%%%$$$!!!***
TRUE
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
Country: Sweden
Valid answers are:
   United States
   India
   China
   Brazil
   Pakistan
Country: China
Crop Type [food fiber]: food
Seed [corn wheat rice]: wheat
CLIPS>
```

To allow the first question to display the valid responses, redefine the questions deffacts to include an initial question that has already been answered:

```
(deffacts questions
   (question (name location)
             (text "Country")
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question start-program))
   (question (name crop-type)
             (text "Crop Type")
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question location))
   (question (name seed)
             (text "Seed")
             (display-answers yes)
             (last-question crop-type))
   (response (question start-program)
             (answer yes))
   (branch (question start-program)
           (answer yes)
           (next-question location)
           (next-answers "United States" "India" "China" "Brazil" "Pakistan")))
```

The output will then look like this:

```
CLIPS> (run)
Country ["United States" "India" "China" "Brazil" "Pakistan"]: Sweden
Country ["United States" "India" "China" "Brazil" "Pakistan"]: China
Crop Type [food fiber]: food
Seed [corn wheat rice]: wheat
CLIPS>
```

Comment: that's awesome !! thanks Gary.. I just have one question.. clips is based on forward chaining , how does the above solution fit the forward chaining requirement?

Comment: In a backward chaining system, you'd start with the goal of selecting a seed and then move backwards to determine the questions you'd need to ask to make that selection. In this case, you're starting with the initial question(s) to ask and then proceeding down each valid path as the questions are answered.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Apologies for the delayed response. One final question, should I code every possible scenario in Clips for a particular use case?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what you mean since it seems like that would be part of your program requirements as to whether you have to handle every scenario. If you have a fact indicating the final response desired (e.g. seed), you could write a low salience rule which fires if a final response is not found. Since the questions are represented as facts, you could also write some meta rules to analyze them to determine if there are any questions which can't be reached.